# Issue with starting the elastic job through Autosys job

Tags: elasticsearch, autosys

I installed elastic search in our Unix box. By switching to a super user, i am able to start the elastic engine

I configured a Autosys job for the above operation, By giving the owner as super user used in the Unix box.

Issue: From the autosys job i am getting the following exception

> [2019-06-07T09:32:39,922][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap ] node validation exception [2] bootstrap checks failed [1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536] [2]: memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked

I already increased file descriptor value to 100000. Still getting the same exception.

Could some one please suggest me what could be the issue causing this error

Thanks, Vasudha

Comment: Can you run `ulimit -n` on all nodes of your cluster ? There is probably a node where you have a value of 4096. To change the limit use `ulimit -n 65536` as sudo and restart elasticsearch.

Comment: HI  Pierre-Nicolas Mougel,  I tried what you have suggested , but i am still getting the same issue